# How to debug out of memory in tensorflow2-gpu

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.x

I am using tensorflow-2 gpu with tf.data.Dataset.
Training on small models works.

When training a bigger model, everything works at first : gpu is used, the first epoch works with no trouble (but I am using most of my gpu memory).

At validation time, I run into a CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY with various allocation with a smaller and smaller amount of bytes that could not be allocated (ranging from 922Mb to 337Mb).
I currently have no metrics and no callbacks and am using `tf.keras.Model.fit`.
If I remove the validation data, the training continues.

What is my issue ? how can I debug this ?

In tf1, I could use `RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom=True)`, does any equivalent exist in tf2 ?

This occurs with tensorflow==2.1.0 .

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

These did not occur in 
2.0 alpha TensorFlow but in 2.0.

Pip installs tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0: has 
leaked memory!
Pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha: 
it's all right!

Try it out

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am using tf 2.1 . Is it still true ? Can you link me to a github issue or another feed ? I am going to try that.